# Apache superset integration with angular in iframe

Tags: python, angular

I want to integrate my apache superset in Angular 11 with iframe i get "access_token", and "csrf_token" through python but not getting 'guest_token" i need help to get this token and want to know how i will integrate this in frontend Angular 11.

i have read document of apache superset google, chatgpt and many other options.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.